# Using sequence of least squares solutions to solve non-linear problems?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, homotopy-theory, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I do know about the **iteratively reweighted least-squares** and have played around with it to some success finding non-linear solutions (like minimizing non-2-norms to achieve solutions which seem to be more sparse). I know some optimization concepts like continuation/homotopy and suspect there could be other similar methods using sequences of linear solutions to approximate non-linear optimization problems. Does anyone have any good pointer of where to start looking?

Comment: What is the problem you would like to solve? Could you state it?

Comment: I'm just curious of such methods in general. Don't have any particular problem in mind.

Comment: instead solving a single non-convex problem you can solve a serie of convex problem 
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-009-9456-5
This method is also known as Successive convex approximation. Guys from wireless communication use it quite frequently.